# What is the best practice to use profiler data from production system?

Tags: symfony, production-environment, symfony-2.6

Assuming I have a running symfony application and it encounters an exception with following configuration:

```
framework:
    profiler:
        lifetime:    604800
        only_exceptions: true
```

Then there should be a dump with profiling information.

But what happen next?
Just copy the file to your own local profiler data folder and start the profiler?

What are the best practices to handle and debug exceptions occuring on the production system?

Answer (score 0):

I think enabling profiler even with `only_exceptions: true` should have performance impact, because to display something on exception is should be collected first in any way.

If you want to see the profiler data from another host, you can [export and import it locally](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#accessing-the-profiling-information)

For me more correct way is to just log events or email exception with stacktrace to admin via kernel exception listeners. Within listener you can access any info you need to send or log, i.e. request stack, logged in user info etc